Is my flair broken for some reason?
I've received reports that Firefox, Chrome, and Vivaldi users can see my flair, but on Safari I just get (console message)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () (5546231.png, line 0)

and the "image didn't load" UI:

Commenters below get mixed results, but some repros use other browsers. Meanwhile some Safari users can see my flair. So I’m not sure what’s going on. (It doesn’t work on mobile Safari either, FWIW.)
The request (omitting cookies) was
:method: GET
:scheme: https
:authority: stackexchange.com
:path: /users/flair/5546231.png
Accept: image/webp,image/avif,image/jxl,image/heic,image/heic-sequence,video/*;q=0.8,image/png,image/svg+xml,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: stackexchange.com
Referer: https://stackexchange.com/users/5546231/d-ben-knoble?tab=flair
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.3 Safari/605.1.15

With a response of
:status: 500
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 89244b0c4f237bea-RIC
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 11 Jun 2024 20:18:56 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: cloudflare
Set-Cookie: prov=852ea734-b5d3-a82a-fb90-8883b5f989ea; expires=Wed, 11 Jun 2025 20:18:56 GMT; domain=.stackexchange.com; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-guid: 984e61b8-f532-415f-ab00-f3de76a21a29


FWIW I can see it in Safari (Version 17.5 (19618.2.12.11.6) MacOS Sonoma 14.5)

Can repro https://i.sstatic.net/YFFGtZnx.png vivaldi/windows 11 - and in a different part of the world

I've also been able to reproduce this in both Firefox and Edge on Windows 11, as well as Firefox on Android. My own flair works fine, but not Ben's

Ben's seems broken in Chrome 124.0.6367.91 on macOS Catalina, but I can see mine

Oh, it’s just mine that’s broken? Hooray
